# flexbox layout on iphone not taking up the right amount of space

Tags: javascript, css, ios, progressive-web-apps

I've been trying to get this layout to work for smart phones.  What I'm looking to do is have a fixed header that doesn't move and then have a flex container underneath the header that takes up the rest of the screen space.  Inside the flex container should be 3 sections of the same size that each takes up the size the flex-container.

My current attempt isn't working.  I can't figure out how to keep the fixed header from moving and I can't figure out how to get the flex container the right size with each of the sections.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>scroll</title>
        <style>
            html{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
            }
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
            }
            #container{
                height:100%;
                overflow:scroll;
            }
            #fixed{
                postion:fixed;
                top:0;
                height:20%;
                background-color:lightblue;
            }
            #flex-container{
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:column;
                justify-content:space-around;
                height:80%;
            }
            .sections{
                height:80%;
            }
            #section1,#section3{
                background-color:blue;
            }
            
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='fixed'>
                
            </div>
            <div id='flex-container'>
                <div id='section1' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
                <div id='section2' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
                <div id='section3' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the position to *fixed* or *absolute*, the element's position must be definite. You either have to additionally set the navbar's *width* to 100%, or add both the *left: 0* and *right: 0* properties. 
 
Also, don't set each of your sections to *height: 80%*, but only the flex container. Ensure that each flex item has the *flex: 1* property.

Your code should now look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>scroll</title>
        <style>
            html{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
            }
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
            }
            #container{
                height:100%;
                overflow:scroll;
            }
            #fixed{
                postion:fixed;
                top:0;
                height:20%;
                width: 100%;
                background-color:lightblue;
            }
            #flex-container{
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:column;
                justify-content:space-around;
                height:80%;
            }
            .sections{
                flex: 1;
            }
            #section1,#section3{
                background-color:blue;
            }
            
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='fixed'>
                
            </div>
            <div id='flex-container'>
                <div id='section1' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
                <div id='section2' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
                <div id='section3' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this does not work. each of the sections should take up the entire viewport below the fixed header.